# How can I install downloaded zipped drivers for a Canon laser printer LBP 810?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, printer

How can I install a zipped downloaded Canon laser printer LBP810 driver?

I cannot find the setup to install.

Answer (score 1):

From the Start menu, open `Devices and Printers`, then right-click the printer you'd like to update and select `Printer Properties`.  Go to the `Advanced` tab and click `New Driver`, which will bring the wizard, where you can tell it to use the files from **unzipped** file you downloaded.

Comment: Windows 95/98/ME/2000 - Printers, XP - Printers and Faxes, Vista - Printers, Windows 7/8 - Devices and Printers

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the zipped folder in windows explorer, "unzip" or "extract all", then if there is a ".exe" file in the extracted folder, double click on it and it will begin installing.